# How can we get the current exchange rate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have payment gateway and Fedex shipping in our project. Problem is if the person is from some other country then we have to charge different rates for shipping. How can we get the current exchange rate. Is there any service available?

Comment: Isn't your payment gateway able to handle that side of things for you?

Comment: @LukeH: I don't know I am given some existing code base and it is using some hardcoded value like from US to Canada it is 1.03 or something. When I told them this is not correct they said you do not have to worry about all these things :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a webservice, that offers this functionality: http://www.xignite.com/xCurrencies.asmx

Answer (score 1):

you could use either [XE.com](http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=GBP) or use the google search keywords (eg "[1 USD in GBP](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=1+USD+in+GBP&aq=0&aqi=g1g-v2g-j1&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8dc103ef27e8de8e&biw=1579&bih=905)")